# How can i use Multiple layout with same ID's in a Single fragment using ViewBinding in Android

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewbinding

The below code to return the any layout based on the condition check,and **Both layout's are same id's** ,
Then how to handle the Textview setText() or Button onClick() scenario in this layout Using ViewBinding.

For example, Suppose we used the any Textview setText(" ") in that inflated layout, Then how can i get which layout object name(**binding** or **binding1**) are should be set the value of the Textview.

**Code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    View view;

    FirstLayoutBinding binding = FirstLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
    SecondLayoutBinding binding1 = SecondLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
    
    if (isTrue){
        view = binding.getRoot();
    }else  {
        view = binding1.getRoot();
    }
  
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Are able to inflate any layout based on condition check? If yes, you are trying to say how to setText() on TextView which are present in one of those inflated layout? Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rajasekhar exactly you say, but i need know, how to achieve this setText() on Textview  which are presented in one those layout, Using Android ViewBinding concept. Above you can see two layout, but how to achieve the setText() on the selected layout.

Comment: Check my answer, let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: @MohamedTharik were you able to find any solution for you case? i have same usecase on my side as well

Comment: @MohamedTharik were you able to find any solution for you case? i have same usecase on my side as well

Answer (score -1):

Okay let's assume based on your condition check `fragment` will inflate the `SecondLayoutBinding`layout.

Now you have two different `TextViews` in layouts.

In `second_layout.xml` you have `TextView` with `android:id` attribute value `second_text`

In `first_layout.xml` you have `TextView` with `android:id` attribute value `first_text`

Once `fragment` completes inflating in `onCreateView()` with condition. Let's set the text value to the inflated layout's `TextView` only.

So now we inflated with binding `SecondLayoutBinding` and we should `setText()` inside that layout with id `second_text` in `onViewCreated()`.

`onViewCreated()`

```
if (!isTrue) {
    binding1.secondText.setText("MySecondValue");
} else {
    binding.firstText.setText("MyFirstValue");
}
```

One thing you again need to do is, you have check again which view's id you are trying to call to set it's value. If first_layout get's inflated you cannot set value for views or `TextView` inside second_layout and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, But that condition only used with layout inflate. I want given example scenario.

let's assume based on your condition check fragment will inflate the SecondLayoutBindinglayout.

Now you have two different TextViews in layouts but same id.

In second_layout.xml you have TextView with android:id attribute value common_text,

In first_layout.xml you have TextView with android:id attribute value common_text.

Once fragment completes inflating in onCreateView() with condition.
we set the text value to that inflated layout TextView only. No need to write both binding and binding1

Comment: I completely understood the case here. I am again checking the condition because the fragment will only bind reference to the inflated layouts view. Just because the id is same for two different TextViews in two different layouts, it is a good practice to follow this approach, in this way the app will not crash even if you give different id's and have different widgets in it. If the layout is limited to same views and only these textviews then this wouldn't be that much necessary. You can test the code in different ways and see what works best, but I would still write a condition though.